# Calling a Function thats inside a plugin from another .js file

Tags: javascript

I have reviewed many other related question, but still am unable to get this to work.

This is the Plugin:

```
(function($){
    $.fn.smartWizard = function(action) {
        var options = $.extend({}, $.fn.smartWizard.defaults, action);
        var args = arguments;

        return this.each(function(){
                var obj = $(this);
                var curStepIdx = options.selected;
                var steps = $("ul > li > a[href^='#step-']", obj); // Get all anchors in this array
                var contentWidth = 0;
                var loader,msgBox,elmActionBar,elmStepContainer,btNext,btPrevious,btFinish;

                elmActionBar = $('.actionBar',obj);
                if(elmActionBar.length == 0){
                  elmActionBar = $('<div></div>').addClass("actionBar");                
                }

                msgBox = $('.msgBox',obj);
                if(msgBox.length == 0){
                  msgBox = $('<div class="msgBox"><div class="content"></div><a href="#" class="close">X</a></div>');
                  elmActionBar.append(msgBox);                
                }

                $('.close',msgBox).click(function() {
                    msgBox.fadeOut("normal");
                    return false;
                });


                // Method calling logic
                if (!action || action === 'init' || typeof action === 'object') {
                  init();
                }else if (action === 'showMessage') {
                  //showMessage(Array.prototype.slice.call( args, 1 ));
                  var ar =  Array.prototype.slice.call( args, 1 );
                  showMessage(ar[0]);
                  return true;
                }else if (action === 'setError') {
                  var ar =  Array.prototype.slice.call( args, 1 );
                  setError(ar[0].stepnum,ar[0].iserror);
                  return true;
                } else {
                  $.error( 'Method ' +  action + ' does not exist' );
                }

                function init(){
                  var allDivs =obj.children('div'); //$("div", obj);                
                  obj.children('ul').addClass("anchor");
                  allDivs.addClass("content");
                  // Create Elements
                  loader = $('<div>Loading</div>').addClass("loader");
                  elmActionBar = $('<div></div>').addClass("actionBar");
                  elmStepContainer = $('<div></div>').addClass("stepContainer");
                  btNext = $('<a>'+options.labelNext+'</a>').attr("href","#").addClass("buttonNext");
                  btPrevious = $('<a>'+options.labelPrevious+'</a>').attr("href","#").addClass("buttonPrevious");
                  btFinish = $('<a>'+options.labelFinish+'</a>').attr("href","#").addClass("buttonFinish");

                  // highlight steps with errors
                  if(options.errorSteps && options.errorSteps.length>0){
                    $.each(options.errorSteps, function(i, n){
                      setError(n,true);
                    });
                  }


                  elmStepContainer.append(allDivs);
                  elmActionBar.append(loader);
                  obj.append(elmStepContainer);
                  obj.append(elmActionBar); 
                  if (options.includeFinishButton) {
                    elmActionBar.append(btFinish);
                  }
                  elmActionBar.append(btNext).append(btPrevious); 
                  contentWidth = elmStepContainer.width();

                  $(btNext).click(function() {
                      if($(this).hasClass('buttonDisabled')){
                        return false;
                    }
                    doForwardProgress();
                    if ($.isFunction(options.onNext)) {
                        if (!options.onNext.call(this, $(steps))) {
                        }
                    }
                      return false;
                  }); 
                  $(btPrevious).click(function() {
                      if($(this).hasClass('buttonDisabled')){
                        return false;
                    }
                    doBackwardProgress();
                    if ($.isFunction(options.onPrevious)) {
                        if (!options.onPrevious.call(this, $(steps))) {
                        }
                    }
                      return false;
                  }); 
                  $(btFinish).click(function() {
                      if(!$(this).hasClass('buttonDisabled')){
                         if($.isFunction(options.onFinish)) {
                            if(!options.onFinish.call(this,$(steps))){
                              return false;
                            }
                         }else{
                           var frm = obj.parents('form');
                           if(frm && frm.length){
                             frm.submit();
                           }                         
                         }                      
                      }

                      return false;
                  }); 

                  $(steps).bind("click", function(e){
                      if(steps.index(this) == curStepIdx){
                        return false;                    
                      }
                      var nextStepIdx = steps.index(this);
                      var isDone = steps.eq(nextStepIdx).attr("isDone") - 0;
                      if(isDone == 1){
                        LoadContent(nextStepIdx);                    
                      }
                      return false;
                  }); 

                  // Enable keyboard navigation                 
                  if(options.keyNavigation){
                      $(document).keyup(function(e){
                          if(e.which==39){ // Right Arrow
                            doForwardProgress();
                          }else if(e.which==37){ // Left Arrow
                            doBackwardProgress();
                          }
                      });
                  }
                  //  Prepare the steps
                  prepareSteps();
                  // Show the first slected step
                  LoadContent(curStepIdx);                  
                }

                function prepareSteps(){
                  if(!options.enableAllSteps){
                    $(steps, obj).removeClass("selected").removeClass("done").addClass("disabled"); 
                    $(steps, obj).attr("isDone",0);                 
                  }else{
                    $(steps, obj).removeClass("selected").removeClass("disabled").addClass("done"); 
                    $(steps, obj).attr("isDone",1); 
                  }

                    $(steps, obj).each(function(i){
                        $($(this).attr("href"), obj).hide();
                        $(this).attr("rel",i+1);
                  });
                }

                function LoadContent(stepIdx){
                    var selStep = steps.eq(stepIdx);
                    var ajaxurl = options.contentURL;
                    var hasContent =  selStep.data('hasContent');
                    stepNum = stepIdx+1;
                    if(ajaxurl && ajaxurl.length>0){
                       if(options.contentCache && hasContent){
                           showStep(stepIdx);                          
                       }else{
                           $.ajax({
                            url: ajaxurl,
                            type: "POST",
                            data: ({step_number : stepNum}),
                            dataType: "text",
                            beforeSend: function(){ loader.show(); },
                            error: function(){loader.hide();},
                            success: function(res){ 
                              loader.hide();       
                              if(res && res.length>0){  
                                 selStep.data('hasContent',true);            
                                 $($(selStep, obj).attr("href"), obj).html(res);
                                 showStep(stepIdx);
                              }
                            }
                          }); 
                      }
                    }else{
                      showStep(stepIdx);
                    }
                }

                function showStep(stepIdx){
                    var selStep = steps.eq(stepIdx); 
                    var curStep = steps.eq(curStepIdx);
                    if(stepIdx != curStepIdx){
                      if($.isFunction(options.onLeaveStep)) {
                        if(!options.onLeaveStep.call(this,$(curStep))){
                          return false;
                        }
                      }
                    }     
                    if (options.updateHeight)
                        elmStepContainer.height($($(selStep, obj).attr("href"), obj).outerHeight());               
                    if(options.transitionEffect == 'slide'){
                      $($(curStep, obj).attr("href"), obj).slideUp("fast",function(e){
                            $($(selStep, obj).attr("href"), obj).slideDown("fast");
                            curStepIdx =  stepIdx;                        
                            SetupStep(curStep,selStep);
                          });
                    } else if(options.transitionEffect == 'fade'){                      
                      $($(curStep, obj).attr("href"), obj).fadeOut("fast",function(e){
                            $($(selStep, obj).attr("href"), obj).fadeIn("fast");
                            curStepIdx =  stepIdx;                        
                            SetupStep(curStep,selStep);                           
                          });                    
                    } else if(options.transitionEffect == 'slideleft'){
                        var nextElmLeft = 0;
                        var curElementLeft = 0;
                        if(stepIdx > curStepIdx){
                            nextElmLeft1 = contentWidth + 10;
                            nextElmLeft2 = 0;
                            curElementLeft = 0 - $($(curStep, obj).attr("href"), obj).outerWidth();
                        } else {
                            nextElmLeft1 = 0 - $($(selStep, obj).attr("href"), obj).outerWidth() + 20;
                            nextElmLeft2 = 0;
                            curElementLeft = 10 + $($(curStep, obj).attr("href"), obj).outerWidth();
                        }
                        if(stepIdx == curStepIdx){
                            nextElmLeft1 = $($(selStep, obj).attr("href"), obj).outerWidth() + 20;
                            nextElmLeft2 = 0;
                            curElementLeft = 0 - $($(curStep, obj).attr("href"), obj).outerWidth();                           
                        }else{
                            $($(curStep, obj).attr("href"), obj).animate({left:curElementLeft},"fast",function(e){
                              $($(curStep, obj).attr("href"), obj).hide();
                            });                       
                        }

                        $($(selStep, obj).attr("href"), obj).css("left",nextElmLeft1);
                        $($(selStep, obj).attr("href"), obj).show();
                        $($(selStep, obj).attr("href"), obj).animate({left:nextElmLeft2},"fast",function(e){
                          curStepIdx =  stepIdx;                        
                          SetupStep(curStep,selStep);                      
                        });
                    } else{
                        $($(curStep, obj).attr("href"), obj).hide(); 
                        $($(selStep, obj).attr("href"), obj).show();
                        curStepIdx =  stepIdx;                        
                        SetupStep(curStep,selStep);
                    }
                    return true;
                }

                function SetupStep(curStep,selStep){
                   $(curStep, obj).removeClass("selected");
                   $(curStep, obj).addClass("done");

                   $(selStep, obj).removeClass("disabled");
                   $(selStep, obj).removeClass("done");
                   $(selStep, obj).addClass("selected");
                   $(selStep, obj).attr("isDone",1);
                   adjustButton();
                   if($.isFunction(options.onShowStep)) {
                      if(!options.onShowStep.call(this,$(selStep))){
                        return false;
                      }
                   } 
                }                

                function doForwardProgress(){
                  var nextStepIdx = curStepIdx + 1;
                  if(steps.length <= nextStepIdx){
                    if(!options.cycleSteps){
                      return false;
                    }                  
                    nextStepIdx = 0;
                  }
                  LoadContent(nextStepIdx);
                }

                function doBackwardProgress(){
                  var nextStepIdx = curStepIdx-1;
                  if(0 > nextStepIdx){
                    if(!options.cycleSteps){
                      return false;
                    }
                    nextStepIdx = steps.length - 1;
                  }
                  LoadContent(nextStepIdx);
                }  

                function adjustButton(){
                  if(!options.cycleSteps){                
                    if(0 >= curStepIdx){
                      $(btPrevious).addClass("buttonDisabled");
                    }else{
                      $(btPrevious).removeClass("buttonDisabled");
                    }
                    if((steps.length-1) <= curStepIdx){
                      $(btNext).addClass("buttonDisabled");
                    }else{
                      $(btNext).removeClass("buttonDisabled");
                    }
                  }
                  // Finish Button 
                  if(!steps.hasClass('disabled') || options.enableFinishButton){
                    $(btFinish).removeClass("buttonDisabled");
                  }else{
                    $(btFinish).addClass("buttonDisabled");
                  }                  
                }

                function showMessage(msg){
                  $('.content',msgBox).html(msg);
                    msgBox.show();
                }

                function setError(stepnum,iserror){
                  if(iserror){                    
                    $(steps.eq(stepnum-1), obj).addClass('error')
                  }else{
                    $(steps.eq(stepnum-1), obj).removeClass("error");
                  }                                   
                }                        
        });  
    };  

    // Default Properties and Events
    $.fn.smartWizard.defaults = {
          selected: 0,  // Selected Step, 0 = first step   
          keyNavigation: true, // Enable/Disable key navigation(left and right keys are used if enabled)
          enableAllSteps: false,
          updateHeight: true,
          transitionEffect: 'fade', // Effect on navigation, none/fade/slide/slideleft
          contentURL:null, // content url, Enables Ajax content loading
          contentCache:true, // cache step contents, if false content is fetched always from ajax url
          cycleSteps: false, // cycle step navigation
          includeFinishButton: false, // whether to show a Finish button
          enableFinishButton: false, // make finish button enabled always
          errorSteps:[],    // Array Steps with errors
          labelNext:'Next',
          labelPrevious:'Previous',
          labelFinish:'Finish',          
          onLeaveStep: null, // triggers when leaving a step
          onShowStep: null,  // triggers when showing a step
          onFinish: null,  // triggers when Finish button is clicked
          onNext: null,  // triggers when Finish button is clicked
          onPrevious: null  // triggers when Finish button is clicked
    };    

})(jQuery);
```

This is how I am calling:

```
<span class="LinkMe" onclick="showStep(0);">
```

I understand that using a selector to grab the click event is preferable.

How do I properly call the showStep() function, or is it not possible?

EDIT:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function ($) {
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#wizard').smartWizard({
                selected: 0,  // Selected Step, 0 = first step       
                keyNavigation: true, // Enable/Disable key navigation(left and right keys are used if enabled)    
                enableAllSteps: true,  // Enable/Disable all steps on first load    
                transitionEffect: 'fade', // Effect on navigation, none/fade/slide/slideleft    
                contentURL: null, // specifying content url enables ajax content loading    
                contentCache: true, // cache step contents, if false content is fetched always from ajax url    
                cycleSteps: false, // cycle step navigation    
                enableFinishButton: true, // makes finish button enabled always    
                errorSteps: [],    // array of step numbers to highlighting as error steps    
                labelNext: 'Next', // label for Next button    
                labelPrevious: 'Previous', // label for Previous button    
                labelFinish: 'Buy Now',  // label for Finish button  
                // Events
                onLeaveStep: null, // triggers when leaving a step    
                onShowStep: ShowComp_Price,  // triggers when showing a step    
                onFinish: null,  // triggers when Finish button is clicked
                onNext: NextBtnClick,  // triggers when Next button is clicked
                onPrevious: PrevBtnClick  // triggers when Previous button is clicked
            });
        })
    })(jQuery)
</script>
```

Comment: how are you initializing the plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`showStep` is not visible in the global scope, which is why DOM0 binding doesn't work.

The only way this *will* work is if you expose the `showStep` function in the global scope, which requires changing the source code inside the plugin.

Comment: Is it possible to add a new function that can be exposed to the global scope but pull from the variables?

Comment: No. The variables are function scoped; by definition they cannot be accessed outside of the function to which they are scoped.

Comment: Do you think adding a class/id handler inside the plugin will work?

Comment: Depends entirely on what you mean. So, maybe.

Comment: I have to run but i can't demo the code.  You can create a global scope variable and assign a new function to call showStep or assign showStep directly to the global variable,  Like Matt said though, you have to modify the plugin.  Additionally, i know this creates a lot of new issues especially with multiple instantiations of the plugin. I'm just making starting point suggestion.